# Undefined index while image uploading in PHP

Tags: php, file-upload, image-uploading

This is my web service which is image upload from android to php server. I run this service in Advance Rest Client, but Undefined index error occur every time.

This is my php file:

```
<?php   
session_start();
include('classes/mainclass.php');
header('Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
$CustomHeaders = apache_request_headers();

$category=array();

$main_cat = $_POST['main_cat'];
$sub_cat = $_POST['sub_cat'];
$content_name = $_POST['content_name'];
$address=$_POST['address'];
$contact=$_POST['contact'];
$website=$_POST['website'];
$email=$_POST['email'];
$additional=$_POST['additional'];
//$imgurl=$_POST['imageurl'];


$dataObj = new UserClass();

$target_dir = "uploads/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);

$imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
    $imageUrl = $target_dir.basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);

    $result1 = $dataObj->requestcontent($main_cat,$sub_cat,$content_name,$address,$contact,$website,$email,$additional,$imageUrl);

            if($result1)
            {       
                ResponseClass::ResponseMessage("1","Content Request Submitted","True");

            }
            else
            {

                ResponseClass::ResponseMessage("2","Content Request Not Submitted","False");
            }



} else {
    echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
}
?>
```

[image: Error look like this..]

Comment: Make sure you request is in post

Comment: is your request content type json or key value?

Comment: request is in post @B.Desai

Comment: request content type is urlencoded @suraj

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use if condition for post values. That means

```
if(isset($_POST){$main_cat = $_POST['main_cat'];$sub_cat = $_POST['sub_cat'];$content_name =$_POST['content_name'];$address=$_POST['address'];$contact=$_POST['contact'];$website=$_POST['website'];$email=$_POST['email'];$additional=$_POST['additional'];}
```

Comment: Code all on one line is hard to read, and you don't need to do `isset($_POST)` - the array itself is always available.